# Opened older Xcode, Messed up ios app. 3.5 Resolution and no icon either

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, resolution

I accidentally opened my project in an older version of xCode (I believe this is what caused the problem) and since then my iOS application has gotten messed up.

It started running in 3.5 inch resolution in the 4inch simulator as well as my 4 inch iphone 5s. It runs the squished 3.5 version of it and this wasn't happening before.

Furthermore the icon no longer works even though there is an icon in the project.

Something must have gotten corrupted or changed and I'm breaking my head trying to figure this out.

Thanks,

Kenneth

Comment: A little late but use Git, it is build into Xcode -- commit often. Also TimeMachine can be a real lifesaver, I used it yesterday. We all tend to learn the hard way, the important part is to learn and alter behavior.

Comment: Thanks Zaph, and definitely! I have been relying on snapshots but I have learned they are completely unreliable in situations like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the resolution but for the icons check your *info.plist* file, may be that your **CFBundleIcons** dictionary got corrupted.

Comment: Hey peter, in my <product>-Info.plist I see no CSBundleIcons, is that the place I should be looking for that?

Answer (score 0):

After hours and hours I figured it out!

The problem was the images.xcassets.

I deleted this and created and a brand new one and it fixed the issue.

I am so relieved to have found the solution.